# Avoid newline in list-directed output with Intel Fortran compiler

Tags: io, formatting, fortran

I have noticed the results of list-directed output `write(*,*)` in Fortran is compiler dependent.

Indeed, with the code:

```
program one
real(8), dimension(5):: r1
do i=1,5
    r1(i)=sqrt(i*10.0)
end do
write(*,*) (r1(i), i =1,5)
end program one
```

intel compiler ifort gives standard output broken by a newline:

```
   3.16227769851685        4.47213602066040        5.47722530364990     
   6.32455539703369        7.07106781005859
```

while gfortran gives the equivalent one line result:

```
    3.1622776601683795        4.4721359549995796        5.4772255750516612        6.3245553203367590        7.0710678118654755
```

I think that ifort is writing maximum 3 items per line (when floating real numbers). 
Is there any way to make the ifort output be like gfrotran, i.e. avoid the newline?
Ideally, I would like to keep list-directed output `(*,*)` instructions, so I am looking for something like a compiler option or so, if any.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since verson 14, intel fortran compiler has the wrap-margin function. By default, the record is wrapped after 80 characters. For disabling this restriction, you should specify:

on Linux: -no-wrap-margin

on WIndows: /wrap-margin-

See more on [Intel Fortran's reference guide](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/691740)

Comment: Note there may be some problems http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24492202/iforts-no-wrap-margin-works-only-partially but still the best answer

Answer (score 7):

No.  List-directed (free-format) output provides convenience, but you give up control.  Various aspects of the output are unspecified and allowed to be chosen to the compiler.  If you want full control, you have to use formatted output.

Answer (score 2):

Look into edit descriptors in your favorite Fortran book or online documentation. You can use `fmt` specifier in the `write` statement to specify edit descriptors. For example:

```
write(*,fmt='(5(F6.4,3X))') (r1(i), i =1,5)
```

should output something similar to:

```
3.1623   4.4721   5.4772   6.3246   7.0711
```

Comment: thank you but I still mean "free format" instruction. Sometimes (especially in debugging phase, when quick outputs are needed) the size of the array is parameter-dependent and so the formatting is an annoying task.

Comment: You could use the `FMT` specifier in conjunction with a `DO` loop and `ADVANCE="no"`. Might be an extra few lines of code, but if it's what you want....

Comment: @gluuke OK, what you are looking for is list-directed output, not free format. I edited your question accordingly.

Answer (score -2):

See https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/401555

Specify FORT_FMT_RECL or use
write (*,"*(G0,1X))"

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.