# ifort's no-wrap-margin works only partially

Tags: fortran, gfortran, intel-fortran

for some unfortunate reasons I have to use ifort, the "problem" is that ifort truncates long (>80 characters) write(*,*) lines by default (this doesn't happen in gfortran). There's an option called -no-wrap-margin that supposedly recovers the gfortran behavior, which is to write lines as long as I want in a single line. However this only works for lines with less than 8184 characters. A line longer than that, as for example the one obtained with

```
program main
    implicit none
    integer :: i
    write(*,*) (i, i=1, 683)
end program main
```

results in the last number in the second line of the output. Is there a way to get the behavior I want without specifying a format in the write statement? Have I misunderstood the -no-wrap-margin option?

Comment: Better use use explicit format than worry about these things.

Comment: Well, similar issues will probably crop up with any kind of formatted output... Perhaps you can expand your question to describe why it is necessary to output such long lines? A different solution may exist, but that can't be judged from the present question.

Comment: @sigma I need these long lines because I work with programs that create huge matrices for other programs to read afterwards. These other programs rely on having one line per row. I'm fine with writing the format explicitly but I was wondering if there was a simple way of saving some typing by not specifying the format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-no-wrap-margin` option disables the default check in Intel Fortran for the length of output records, which is a remnant from [older times](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/500690#comment-1778058).

Unfortunately, however, the Intel implementation seems to impose a limit of around 2^15 (= 32768) bytes of output, or 8192 default (4 byte) integers, forcing the excess to a new line, which gfortran does not, as you observed.

As an upside, Intel has implemented the [unlimited format item](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2009/07/01/doctor-fortran-in-revert-revert-the-end-of-the-format-is-nigh). Applied to your example code, it could look as follows:

```
program main
    implicit none
    integer :: i
    write(*,'(*(I0,X))') (i, i=1, 683)
end program main
```

Comment: Not sure if I'm following you, but are you referring to the buffer of the terminal? Because compiling with gfortran does not lead to truncated (in the sense that newline characters are inserted) lines for lines just as big as the ones I'm using, so it cannot be a matter of the buffer of the terminal.

Comment: Hmm, I can finally see and reproduce what you mean... at first I could swear gfortran was giving exactly the same output as ifort with the flag. Indeed it seems to be an implementation difference between the compilers. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Great, this is just what I was looking for. I have to remark that not only does it solve the problem when compiling with ifort but it also is part of the fortran 2008 standard and so it works with other compilers. Thanks sigma!